# Create table in mPDF using php

Tags: php, mpdf

I am creating a table in mPDF using php, but I my codes are not working. I also tried the FPDF codes that I also found here but it is also not working. Can someone correct my codes?

My current code is already fetching data from my database but I want it to insert into columns, that is the last thing that I want to accomplish.

```
{
    $data['gfDate']= $this->input->post("fdate");
    $data['gtDate']= $this->input->post("tdate");
    $this->load->library('mpdf');
    $this->load->model('mpdf_model');
    $query = $this->mpdf_model->mpdf_gen048($data);


            if($query!=null)

                    {


                    foreach($query as $data){
            $hello .='

                    <img src="'.base_url().'images/ubplogo.png"> </img>

                    ';


                $html_string ='<table border=\"1\">';
                $html_string.='';
                $html_string.='
                        <tr  style=font-weight:bold>
                        <th>AcctNumber</th>
                        <th>AccountName</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        </tr>';
    if($query!=null)
    {
        foreach($query as $q)
        {
            $html_string .= '<tr>';
            $html_string .= '<td>'.$q->accnum.'</td>';
            $html_string .= '<td>'.$q->accname.'</td>';
            $html_string .= '<td>'.$q->add1.'</td>';
            $html_string .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html_string.='</table>';
    }

            }


            $mpdf=new mPDF('ISO-8859-1','letter', 10, 'Arial', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9, 'P');

                $stylesheet = file_get_contents(base_url().'css/pdf.css');

                ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

                $mpdf->cacheTables = true;
                $mpdf->simpleTables=true;
                $mpdf->packTableData=true;
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
                $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img src="'.base_url().'css/edrsletter.jpg"></img>');
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($hello);
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_string);                 
                $mpdf->SetFooter(' Sample PDF template  - {PAGENO}');
                $mpdf->Output();



            }

    }
```

Comment: Try making table HTML valid. `<tr style=font-weight:bold>` => `<tr style="font-weight: bold;">`. Also there is no need to escape `border="1"` since you start with `'` and attribute uses `"`. And if `$query` is null, than you will never close table.

Comment: Thanks~!, about the null in my `$query` I believe that `!=` means not null so it will run if there is a data to fetch. anyway I will try your suggestion. thank you!

Comment: Yes, it will run, but if there is no data, no `if ($query != null)` will be executed and there will not be `$html_string.='</table>';` appended to table.

Comment: I see, I am still having this error message as of the moment so I am not able to see the result **mPDF error: When using cacheTables, you must have read/write access to cache files**. What do you think is the right condition to for my query instead of `!=`?

Comment: Error means you don't have permissions to access cache files. `!=` may be changed to `if (!is_null($query))`. Just move `$html_string.='</table>';` out of *if*